# VC++ wcsftime (strftime) does not return proper locale string with %x

Tags: c++, visual-c++, strftime

My Windows7 region is "US", but I manually customized the Windows Date format: "mm/dd/yy" ==> "yyyy-mm-dd" in Control Panel > Region > ...

Now if I run a small C++ app (VC++2015)

```
int main()
{
    struct tm time; 
    time = "2016.october.31"; /*pseudo code*/

    wchar_t buffer[128];
    wcsftime(buffer, 127, L"%x", &time);
 }
```

> buffer = "10/31/16" instead of **expected** customized windows locale date format: "2016-10-31"

What is the problem here?
`wcsftime` does not care about customized locale settings?

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `setlocale("")` first, to switch to system locale. Initially, the program runs in C locale.

Comment: Brilliant, this seems to solve the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the original issue is more, as in VS2008, if you call  `std::locale::global(std::locale("English_United States.1252"))` , that will make `wcsftime(buffer, 127, L"%x", &time);` generate a proper user locale string, but in VS2015, it does not. Calling with "" in 2015 solves it, but very strange. I expect the 2008 STL implementation was not ok.